# fatal error invalid Collection count differed in successive traversals

Tags: ios, swift, collections, iteration, tuples

I have an array of tuples declared like this.

```
fileprivate var locations: [(location: CLLocation, time: Date)] = []
```

I capture location updates every 2 seconds and add them to this array.

```
func didReceiveLocation(_ location: CLLocation) {
    let location = (location, Date())
    locations.append(location)
}
```

Simultaneously, I run a timer with 1 second interval to update a map with these collected location data. It basically draws the path.

```
fileprivate func updateDashboard() {
    let locations = self.locations.map { $0.location } // crash

    let path = GMSMutablePath()
    for location in locations {
        path.add(location.coordinate)
    }

    let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Draw the path on the map
        let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
        polyline.strokeColor = .flatSkyBlue()
        polyline.strokeWidth = 5
        polyline.map = self.mapView

        // Focus the map view to include the drawn path
        self.mapView.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 50))
    }
}
```

This works but sometimes I get a random crash at the first line in the above method (`let locations = self.locations.map { $0.location }`) with the below error message.

> fatal error: invalid Collection: count differed in successive traversals

I *assume* this is because the `map` function is executed again before the previous iteration is finished? If that's the case, how to avoid it?

The only entry regarding this error I could find is this Swift [bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3290). It says that it's fixed but I'm still getting it. I'm on Xcode 8.3.2 by the way.

Comment: Probably has to do with `self.locations` being `append`ed to before the `map` is finished. Copy `self.locations` to a local variable and then `map` over that instead: `var locations = self.locations ; locations = locations.map{$0.location}`.

Comment: `Array`s are not thread safe; you need to synchronise access to your `locations` array.